# How to make PopUpManager correctly show custom component based on spark TitleWindow?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, popup

I use this code to create and show a MessageWindow:

```
   var newTitleWindow:MessageWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(contextView,MessageWindow, true) as MessageWindow;
   newTitleWindow.text = message;
   PopUpManager.centerPopUp(newTitleWindow);
```

MessageWindow source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:TitleWindow title="Something gone wrong" width="200" height="130" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
               close="closeMe()" resize="centerMe()" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" >
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;


        [Bindable]
        public var text:String;

        private function closeMe():void {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }

        private function centerMe():void {
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
        }
        ]]></mx:Script>
    <s:VGroup top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0">
        <s:Label id="lbl" left="10" right="10" textAlign="center" text="{text}"/>
        <s:Button id="btn"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

There is no nested components displayed when I run my app.
[image: s:TitleWindow nested components are not shown]

The debugger shows they are created and visible.

To my "amusement" the components are shown when I replace s:TitleWindow with mx:TitleWindow.
[image: mx:TitleWindow nested components are shown]

I really want to use spark TitleWindow.
Is there any trick to fix this behavior?

Comment: can you give us the code for a runnable sample?  Something is amiss, but it's not obvious what.  I've done the same thing you have, conceptually, w/o any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `mx:Script` with `fx:Script`